# How to mention that I've brought sponsors for my college fest?

Tags: professionalism, resume, linkedin

I'm studying my bachelors in a reputed institution.

As many other colleges do, my college conducts a technical and cultural fest and we generally ask various industries, restaurants, etc. for financial sponsorship in return for the publicity they get in student community.

This year, I was part of the marketing/PR team and I visited several firms/outlets and succesfully convinced them to sponsor.

How should I mention this in my LinkedIn profile or resume?

Should I at all?

Answer (score 1):

List your committee membership, list the roles you performed as a member: one may be acquisition, you've been the 'primary point of contact for several sponsors', you have probably negotiated, (co)signed or drafted sponsorship agreements with these parties... etc.

I have performed a similar role for a student association. Whenever this was brought up in job interviews, they wanted to know what I did, what I learned doing it and what challenges I overcame. Don't name names unless asked. The companies you're interviewing with probably do not hire new graduates for their professional network, and the people you've worked with (at your sponsors) are not usually the real movers and shakers. Plus, the good reputation of your sponsors is not your accomplishment, you may come across as a show-off.

If 'experience dealing with a certain type of company' is relevant to the positions you are applying for (jobs in purchasing, acquisition or sales), you might say: 'a large accountancy/IT firm' or 'several multinationals in finance and insurance' or 'several local businesses'. It gives the interviewer something to ask about (if they do care) and shows that you can be discrete.

Answer (score 1):

You **should mention** this, but not which firms gave money.
This shows a willingness to volunteer and an interest in both your school and your field.

> [school name]'s Annual Technical and Cultural Festival
>   Marketing/PR team member
>   In person visits to several firms resulting in X sponsorships for Y dollars.

You can stick the word "volunteer" in there if you think it is appropriate.
Add in anything else that is appropriate (like if got the most sponsorships or you were top 5 revenue)